# Is there a way to wrap an numpy `ndarray` interface around an existing binary file?

Tags: python, numpy, scapy, mmap, pcap

I have a binary network capture (`.pcapng`) file that contains video data.  I am parsing the `.pcapng` with scapy and I can extract the data, but the video sequences I am working with are very large and the operations I want to perform quickly grind my machine to a halt if I load very much data at once.  One approach to deal with this would be to extract all the data and save it into a mmap file, or better yet, HDF5.  However, before I sign up for making copies of all the data, I wanted to see if it is possible to memory map the existing files in place.  Is there a way to make a discontinuous mmap into an existing file that tells an ndarray object where to find memory associated with a given index, when that memory may be in arbitrary locations within the file?  I haven't found any good analogs in mmap, which assumes a contiguous file is available.  I imagine some `ndarray` subclass that loads up the file, scans the file for the boundaries of all the relevant imagery data within the `.pcapng` file, and provides a custom implementation of `ndarray` `__index__` method that can return the appropriate file offset(s) for a given index or slice.  Is this bonkers, or is there a better (already solved) method for doing this?

Comment: It's unclear. I guess you want to process a huge video file sequentially. Why not decode it and process frame by frame?

Comment: It is possible to decode frame by frame, and I am doing this currently.  Since the files are large, however, and I am trying to load them for video playback (using pytqgraph), I need an array representation with a softer footprint than loading everything into RAM.  HDF5 provides a nice way to do this, but I am hoping not to have to transcode the files to HDF5, so I can browse them at rest instead.

Comment: Did you convert fragments of encoded video in the pcap file into a video file? Then, there's no reason for loading that file as a Numpy array, because it's encoded. How do you decode the video file? Libraries such as PyAV supports seeking the video file.

Comment: The video is unencoded; it is simply raw imagery.

Comment: Then I recommend to implement a producer and consumer pattern, where a worker thread or process produces ```np.array```` frames sequentially and pushes them into a queue or pipe, and the main GUI process pops frames and consumes them. By doing this, you don't need to load all of frames into the memory at once. Think about the buffering of a video playback on YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

Construct a [`mmap.mmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html#mmap.mmap) object from the file and pass that to the `numpy.ndarray` constructor. For example:

```
import os
import numpy

with open("filename", "rb") as f:
    mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)

nd = numpy.ndarray(1000000,buffer=mm)
```

Comment: I guess the OP already knows this and he's asking a different thing, but it's unclear for now. Let's wait his response.

Comment: The video data within the file is discontinuous because it is distributed across packets with headers.  This is exactly what I hoped to do, except that I couldn't find a way to give `mmap` instructions on where the interesting data is, and which data to ignore.